# Uninstall RJSONIO in R

Tags: r, rjsonio

How to uninstall RJSONIO package form R..
What I tried

```
> remove.packages("RJSONIO")
Removing package from ‘/Users/akshit/Library/R/3.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in remove.packages : there is no package called ‘RJSONIO’
```

But if I check the path of the package, I get this

```
> path.package("RJSONIO")
[1] "/Users/XXXXX/Library/R/3.2/library/RJSONIO"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try **detach(package:RJSONIO)**. It worked for me. Please see to the following trial and error:

```
> library(RJSONIO)
> path.package("RJSONIO")
[1] "/home/XXXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RJSONIO"
> remove.packages("RJSONIO")
Removing package from ‘/home/XXXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> path.package("RJSONIO")
[1] "/home/XXXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RJSONIO"
> detach(package:RJSONIO)
> path.package("RJSONIO")
Error in path.package("RJSONIO") : none of the packages are loaded
> library(RJSONIO)
Error in library(RJSONIO) : there is no package called ‘RJSONIO’
> path.package("RJSONIO")
Error in path.package("RJSONIO") : none of the packages are loaded
```